# Quantum vs classic in NP-hard problems

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-hard, np, quantum-computing

Is there any quantum algorithm (algorithm for quantum computers) for any NP-hard problem that has better runtime than the best known classic algorithm's runtime?

Comment: related: [Can a parallel computer simulate a quantum computer?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34544/58382), [Are there problems in which quantum computers are known to provide an exponential advantage?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/135/55), and [Is there any general statement about what kinds of problems can be solved more efficiently using a quantum computer?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1584/55)

Answer (score 3):

It is conjectured that the complexity of SAT on $n$ variables is $\tilde\Omega(2^n)$ (a version of this is SETH, the strong exponential time hypothesis). In contrast, Grover's algorithm solves it in $\tilde O(2^{n/2})$.

On the other hand, it is conjectured that quantum computers cannot solve NP-hard problems in polynomial time, that is $\mathsf{NP} \not\subseteq \mathsf{BQP}$.